# Windows 7 defining variable for bat files and msg command

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, messaging

I have a .bat file like that:

```
msg userA System will be restarted
msg userB System will be restarted
msg userC System will be restarted
msg userD System will be restarted
msg userE System will be restarted
msg userF System will be restarted
msg userG System will be restarted
```

Can I define a variable for message part as like:

```
message = System will be restarted 
msg userA message
msg userB message
msg userC message
msg userD message
msg userE message
msg userF message
```

Also is it possible to define users as an array? As like:

```
users= [userA, userB, userC, userD, userE, userF]
message = System will be restarted 
msg users message
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

**EDIT:** I wrote that lines to a bat file:

```
set MESSAGE = System will be restarted
msg userA %MESSAGE%
```

When I click the bat file I got that screenshot: [image: screenshot]

Comment: SLaks's answer is correct, but I think you spoiled it by putting spaces around `=` in the assignment. The answer doesn't have them and works fine.

Comment: Thanks Andriy. Marking your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes; you can use [environment variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable):

   ```
   set MESSAGE=System will be restarted 
   msg userE %MESSAGE%
   ```
2. [Yes](https://superuser.com/questions/191224/populating-array-in-dos-batch-script):

   ```
   set USERS=(userA userB userC userD userE userF)
   set MESSAGE=System will be restarted 

   for %%i in %USERS% do msg %%i %MESSAGE%
   ```

Comment: When I run the batch file command line appears and writes "Enter message to send; end message by pressing CTRL-Z on a new line, then ENTER"?

Comment: I tried: @echo off
set MESSAGE = System will be restarted
msg murat %MESSAGE% without writing  @echo off

Comment: When I try it from command line it is OK but over a batch file it still asks me for entering message and doesn't recognize defining a variable.

Comment: But what gets echo'd? What is it executing?